# Should question with bad english be closed?

Tags: discussion, flags

Pretty often I come across questions that might have well stated question, but it is written with a lot of spelling mistakes which makes question unreadable. What should be done in this case? Should it be edited appropriately or should it be closed?

Comment: The only time a question should be closed for spelling/grammar is when the problems are so egregious that the asker's intent is unclear and edits cannot be made without making big assumptions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should it be edited appropriately or should it be closed?

It should be edited.

Not everyone writes English well.

There *might* be other reasons for closing a question (duplicate, off-topic etc...), but just spelling and grammar issues are not a good reason.

Comment: But if I cannot even understand? Shouldn't user be asked to improve it?

Comment: @Heisenberg - certainly the user should be asked to improve it. And that one person can't understand it doesn't mean another will too. If the OP doesn't respond and no edits occur, then it is a candidate for  closing and deleting.